Bicep to add networking in "Outbound traffic configuration" in existing azure web app
I need to add regional vnet-subnet integration to existing azure web app, I am using the below module as per MS for that but it just doesn't work
resource vnetIntegration 'Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections@2021-02-01' = {
  parent: webApp
  name: 'vnet'
  properties: {
    vnetResourceId: subnetId
    vnetRouteAllEnabled: false
  }
}

I even added subnetResourceId instead of vnetResourceId but that also didn't work.
If I add a vnet connection manually I get this -

But using the above code it gets stuck on Gateway-based integration like this -


did you add subnet delegation to Microsoft.Web/serverFarms ? => on the subnet itself

yes subnet delegation is there

To integrate an existing web app with virtual network settings under outbound traffic configuration, you need to use Microsoft.Web/sites/networkConfig resource provider instead of
Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections.
Below is the complete Bicep code for your requirement.
param vnetName string = 'jah-${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
var vnetAddress = '10.0.0.0/16'
var subnetAddressPrefix = '10.0.0.0/24'
param subnetname string = 'subnet-${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
param location string = 'Canada Central'

resource webapp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' existing = {
  name: 'appinsights-oct30'
}
resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2022-05-01' = {
  name: vnetName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        vnetAddress
      ]
    }
    subnets: [
      {
        name: subnetname
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: subnetAddressPrefix
          delegations: [
            {
              name: 'delegation'
              properties: {
                serviceName: 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource vnetint 'Microsoft.Web/sites/networkConfig@2023-12-01' = {
  parent: webapp
  name: 'virtualNetwork'
  properties: {
    subnetResourceId: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', vnetName, subnetname)
  }
  dependsOn: [
    vnet
  ]
}

Deployment succeeded:


Refer Github for the similar requirement related to function app.

Great! Thanks. I will give it a try.

Have you tried it? @user
